# textColor is being ignored in a night mode

Tags: android, android-layout, textcolor

I have a few **textViews** with a property `android:textColor="@color/textColor"`.

Color `textColor` is defined in two files: **colors.xml** and **colors-night.xml**

**#000000** and **#4183d7** respectively.

I allow users to change app theme:

1. `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);`
2. `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);`

But if mobile is set to night mode and user tries to set the app to light mode, all **textViews** become white (howewer it must be black)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If dark mode is enabled on a phone, but not in your app - system applies [color inversion](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151800?hl=en-GB). To disable it, we need to use `android:forceDarkAllowed="false"`